# Using fmincon to Create a Hybrid System Sizing Graph

Tags: matlab, optimization, system, hybrid

I am trying to design a Matlab code which creates a sizing graph for a generator-battery system (so that for a particular generator rating you can see the battery capacity required to meet the electrical load). I am basing it on the methodology outlined by Arun et al. (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0360544208000534).

I need to solve the equation:

```
Q(t+1) = Q(t)+ [P(t)-D(t)]f*dt                               (1)
```

subject to the linear constraints:

```
Q(t) ≥ 0                                                 (2)
Q(t=0) = Q(t=T)                                          (3)
```

Where T is the end time (i.e. the battery capacity should be the same at the start and at the end).

I know `D(t)` (the load, a vector), `f` (the efficiency) and `dt = 1`. There are 24 time steps in total (so one day).

`P(t)` is the generator power at each time-step. It will vary as the generator sometimes runs at part load, depending on the load.

I need to find `Q`, the battery capacity, at each time step.

I want to create a Matlab solver to analyse equation 1, subject to constraints 2 and 3, to obtain `Q` and `P` at each time step for a given rated `P`. My initial thought was to use `fmincon`. However I need to integrate this solver with two loops, first looping over the rated power and secondly over the time steps to get `Q(t+1), Q(t)` and `P(t)` at each `t`.

Comment: You shouldn't be passing functions as strings; use [anonymous functions](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), e.g. `@battery_sizing_test_2`. Are the last two lines of the code above inside of the `battery_sizing_test_2` function, making the call recursive? `k` is undefined. And it's probably a bad idea to mix symbolic math (`symsum`) with numerics without making sure to convert the result with [`double`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html). Just use [`sum`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) and indexing, which will be faster.

Comment: Thank you for the help horchler, I have not used anonymus functions before so I shall check them out. The last two lines are not in the code, that was the response when I tried to run it (I shall change the formatting now).

I have made a function which successfully finds the minimum generator rating, now I need to find the corresponding values of Q

Comment: Clean up your question. No one wants to read a bunch of irrelevant stuff (they also don't even need to know the physical significance of the variables). If you're not getting an error any more (I can't tell) remove all of that. Comment your code and make it clear what parts are in separate functions.

Comment: Ok sorry about that, is that better? My current code is not really relevant to this part (my code was to find the minimum generator rating possible) but I am going to have another crack at it over the next couple of days